# Error ao entrar no admin

Tags: magento2

after entering the command

**php -dmemory_limit = 5G bin / magento setup: di: compile**

**php -dmemory_limit = 5G bin / magento setup: static-content: deploy -f**

This error appeared :-

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1129520105273

Comment: Delete the generated/code directory rm -rf generated/code
Then run
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmo -R 0777 var/ pub/ generated/

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do it below.

```
Delete the generated/code directory rm -rf generated/code
Then run
1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. php -dmemory_limit = 5G bin / magento setup: static-content: deploy -f
3. php -dmemory_limit = 5G bin/magento setup:di:compile
4. php bin/magento cache:flush
5. chmo -R 0777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Hope it works.